# How to use 'if' and 'else' function to distinguish answer 'yes' from 'no' in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I`ve just started to learn my first coding language, python.
And I want to give to print() informations in my program, depending from user choice.
I am very fresh so pls be forgiving.

the code:

```
answer = input("Do You like it?" + " Yes/No")
    if answer = (yes)
    print("That`s great!\nThank You" + name + ".")
    else answer == (no)
print("Sorry to hear that\nPerhaps we could use other names?")
```

I want to give to print() informations in my program, depending from user choice.
I am very fresh so pls be forgiving.

Comment: Currently your syntax is incorrect, try to fix it first. Try to begin [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) in official python tutorials and come back with exact problem you're struggling with.

Comment: Some help here: [String Comparison in Python](https://www.askpython.com/python/string/string-comparison-in-python)

Comment: `yes` and `no` should be `'yes'` and `'no'`, you forgot a `=`, `name` is unknown, `else` should be `elif`, you forgot `:` after the conditions, identation is not correct

Comment: Hints: indentation is important - you need to sort that; strings are in quotes `" "` make sure you have used this consistently; `=` is different than `==`

Comment: Is that your real indentation? Also, others have pointed this out, but that's not the correct syntax for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try and modify this code. hope this helps

```
def ifelse():
    entername = input() #first user input
    print('Do you like it?') #first prompt 
    answer = input()
    
    if answer == 'yes': 
        print("That`s great!") 
        print("Thank You name" )
    else:  # you can also use 'elif answer == 'no'
        #but since you only have two choices consider this a shortcut
        print("Sorry to hear that")  
        print("Perhaps we could use other names?")
        
ifelse()
```

ps. you can format the print statement so that the user input 'entername' can be printed along side it [ you can also do this w/o using def fcns]

Comment: Your answer should contain more explanation of what you did to fix it, since the OP is new. (That way they can learn.) Also, additional information should be [edit]ed into the answer itself.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine I know that OP is new but I don't think just comments will help and a visual of a working code can help them understand it more than just technical wording. I do agree that maybe i should've included more explanation